# iTunes says this computer is not authorized

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I have a iPod touch, iOS 4.3, running iTunes 10 on Windows 7. I had an iTunes store without a credit card, because I didn't intend to buy apps anyway. So today I plugged in my iPod and iTunes told me that I should update its OS. I said OK, and it told me that I should transfer my downloaded stuff from the iPod to my iTunes library first. Fair enough, I went to `File > Transfer purchases from iPod` (rough translation, my iTunes' in Spanish), and it told me that I don't have authorization to use them in this computer.

I went to `Store > Give this computer permission` (again, rough translation), and got a message that said that I had to validate (or something like that) that account with the iTunes store. I went to do that, and it asked for credit card information. This time I didn't see a "None" option for the credit card, so I just went ahead and gave it the info.

I tried giving authorization again, but iTunes told me that this computer already had permission, so I tried removing and giving authorization again, but iTunes still tells me that it can't transfer my apps because the computer is not authorized.

So, what's up? Why does iTunes keep telling me to authorize this computer if it's already authorized?

Comment: Do you have another computer to which you connected your iPod, and synchronized with it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I ask because when I updated the iOS on a Mac, I had the same problem, and it was because I was not using the usual Mac I use to synchronize the iPod, even though it was one of the computers that was authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Turns out the email address I had used to register with Apple had a dot in it. I do this because to the Gmail it's the same things, and it allows me to filter out stuff that I may not want. So I tried authorizing with that ID, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` on your iDevice.

Scroll down to `iTunes & Apps`. After touching it, check the Apple ID, which is your email address.

Go to iTunes on your computer and check the email address that is signed in.

If it is different from the one on your device, you need to sign out and sign in under the Apple ID on your device. Make sure you authorize this computer for this device/Apple ID.